# How to use same button after setoncompletitionlistener?

Tags: java, android, button, audio, android-mediaplayer

After I set oncompletetionlistener for MediaPlayer.
Using the same button again after the mediaplayer is release, it crashes the app. How do I call a event to play audio after the media player is release?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button bt1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
            mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp1.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you release the media player you have to reintialiaze the **MediaPlayer** object.

if (mp1 == null)
       mp1 = new Media player();

Comment: if I reinitialize the MediaPlayer object. The if (mp1 == null) mp1 = new Media player(); needs to be after mp1.release; ?

Comment: Yup depends, one thing you can do that intialize Media player object in onClickListener function just above mp1.start() by checking null.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: I had another questions regarding saving files to android. Not sure if you could answer it or know how to? I ask a separate question

Comment: Make this question solved so no more spamming is done.